# Show output messages from background python script starting at boot

Tags: python, unix, terminal, cron, daemon

I'm running python script at boot on background using crontab.
Therefore, the terminal won't show up on boot and my printing messages doesn't appear to the user.

How can I open up the terminal window at certain point of my program and print output from there? (also getting input from user)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try using "screen" (sudo apt-get install screen). It's a small tool that allows you to run a script in a special terminal that can be closed and reopened without terminating your script. It's very easy to use: instead of `python your-script.py` you simply use `screen python your-script.py`. To reopen the terminal just `screen -r`. This is really great when working over ssh, as you can close your session without stopping the programm that is currently running and if one can start "screen" on boot, this will do what you want (haven't tried it)

Comment: @SimSon thank you, but is doesn't seems to work... there's a flash of the terminal for a second on startup and then nothing.

Comment: I've also tried using gnome-terminal and it yields the same results.

Comment: And you can not access the screen with `screen -r`? You can view active screens with `screen -ls`, doesn't your script appear there?

Comment: @SimSon no... it shows only one screen that is on and thats of the terminal.